# In JSP,Can we use javascript for form validation?

Tags: jsp

Can we use Javascript for Form validation in JSP pages?

Comment: What have you tried and what has failed? That are the questions which you should ask on Stack Overflow. Your question is way too rhetorical and indicates zero research.

Comment: Javascript validation makes the page friendlier to the user and avoids unnecessary round trips to the server. But it is easily circumvented. So, please be sure to repeat the validation on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Why couldn't you? JavaScript is executed at client-side, and doesn't care if the HTML code has been generated by a JSP, a PHP script, or anything else.